# django crispy forms - add field help text?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

Looking through the crispy forms I cannot find if help text is supported. im trying to add some help text to the select multiple field as per the below

```
Field('site_types', Title="Site Types", size="15", help_text="Hold down cmd on MacOS or ctrl on windows to select multiple"),
```

is this supported or would I use some other attribute to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the working example i used to display help text

```
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['site_types'].help_text = "Please select bla bla bla"
```

Answer (score 3):

Haven't used crispy forms in a little bit but I'm pretty certain you just define `help_text` like you would on a regular form. Looking at the [docs](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html), there are some additional configuration options for the help text if you happen to be using the Bootstrap template pack.

Comment: ive done that as above and it doesn't display currently

Answer (score 0):

Rather than define `help_text` in `crispy_forms.layout.Field`, define it where you define choices (or use the solution by Pavan Kumar T S).

### forms.py

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Field

SITE_TYPES = [
    ('business', 'Business'),
    ('education', 'Education'),
    ('entertainment', 'Entertainment'),
    ('news', 'News'),
    ('other', 'Other')
]

class TestForm(forms.Form):
    site_types = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=SITE_TYPES,
        help_text="Hold down cmd on MacOS or ctrl on windows to select multiple"
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('site_types', Title="Site Types", size="15")
        )
```

### Form:

[Form with help text displayed below the field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfgX0.png)